# Alignment with fixed elements and scrollable content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/bdda6m6d/) is a simplified JSFiddle of the problem.

As you can see, the content is beat out of alingment with the header because of the scrollbar.

As far as I know, the only way to deal with this is to calculate the width of the scrollbar using Javascript (David Walsh's excellent [method](http://davidwalsh.name/detect-scrollbar-width) springs to mind) and to set it as `left/right: -scrollbarwidthpx` value to the header.

However, considering the dynamic nature of the page I'm working on, with the headers place in the DOM and position changing depending on at what point the user has scrolled to, this is an option I am hoping to turn to only if there's nothing else I can do.

My question is, is there any way that I can maybe take the scrollbars or the content out of the flow while preserving a scrolling overflow, or otherwise align the two elements using only HTML/CSS? Are scrollbar widths consistent across all browsers/OS's that have them affect   the flow? Or will I have to resort to using Javascript to align them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
}

.scroll {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#content{
    width: 400px;
    height:auto;
    margin: auto;
    background:gray;
}
.header {
    width: 400px;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 60px;
    background: yellow;
    z-index: 10;
}

.content {
    height: 1200px;
    background: linear-gradient(red, orange);
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    border-top:61px solid;
    border-bottom:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
    <div id="content">
      <div class="header"></div>
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```